# AzureML schema "list index out of range" error

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I developed a machine learning model using Azure ML's clustering. Few of the requests made from the cluster are triggering 404 HTTP error. I followed the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-advanced-entry-script) to do modifications in my swagger.json file. Finally ended up with "list index out of range" error. It seems to be having issue with the global parameter but I am no sure about it. I am using the API from postman with some default headers like mentioned in the body below

```
{
    "Inputs": {
         "input_1" : "content"
         "input_2: : "content"
         ......
    },
    "GlobalParameters": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the "GlobalParameter" value to any floating number other than 1.0 or even you can remove it and execute. Sometimes, Global parameter will cause the issue. Check the below documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/746784/azure-ml-studio-error-while-testing-real-time-endp.html